# Java Transposition cipher encrypt/decrypt

Tags: java, encryption

I'm trying to get my transposition cipher to work.

Whenever I input the resulting cipher text of the encryption method into the decryption method, I should get back the original plain text... but that is not the case...

what am I doing wrong?

thanks for the help!

```
public String EncryptTranspositionCipher(){
    String outputstring = "";


    for(int j=0;j<key;j++){
       for(int i=j;i<plainText.length();i+=key){
           outputstring += plainText.charAt(i);
       }
    }
    return outputstring;
 }
 public String DecryptTranspositionCipher(){
      String outputstring = "";
      int stepforDec=0;
      stepforDec= plainText.length() / key;
      for(int j=0;j<stepforDec;j++){
         for(int i=j;i<plainText.length();i+=stepforDec){
             outputstring += plainText.charAt(i);
         }
      }
      return output string; }
```

Comment: What should the algorithm be? I can see some errors, but I don't exactly know what the cipher text should look like...

Answer (score 1):

Look at your `DecryptTranspositionCipher()` method.  Where does it find the cyphertext you want it to decode?  Perhaps you might do better with something like:

```
 public String DecryptTranspositionCipher(String cyphertext){ ... }
```